# POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/register 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When Cloudinary is not included my Code runs fine on Postman. As I include Cloudinary to in register route to add photos to account, I am getting this error

userAction.jsx

```
export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_REQUEST });
  
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
  
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/register`, userData, config);
  
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

LoginSignup.jsx

```
import React, {Fragment,useRef,useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./LoginSignUp.css";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOpen';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import img from "../../images/Profile.png";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {clearErrors, login , register} from "../../actions/userAction.jsx";
import {useAlert} from "react-alert";
 

export default function LoginSignUp(){

    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();
    const navigate = useNavigate();


    const {error,loading,isAuthenticated} = useSelector((state)=>state.user);

    const loginTab=useRef(null);
    const registerTab = useRef(null);
    const switcherTab = useRef(null);

    const [loginEmail,setLoginEmail] = useState("");
    const [loginPassword,setLoginPassword] = useState("");

    const [user,setUser] = useState({
        name:"",
        email:"",
        password:"",
    });

    const {name,email,password} = user;

    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(img);
    const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState(img);

    function loginSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch((login(loginEmail,loginPassword)));
    }

    function registerSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        
        const myForm = new FormData();

        myForm.set("name",name);
        myForm.set("email",email);
        myForm.set("password",password);
        myForm.set("avatar",avatar);

        dispatch(register(myForm));
    }

    function registerDataChange(e){
        if(e.target.name==="avatar"){
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = ()=>{
                if(reader.readyState===2){
                    setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
                    setAvatar(reader.result);
                }
            };

            reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
        } else {
            setUser({...user, [e.target.name]:e.target.value});
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(error){
            alert.error(error);
            dispatch(clearErrors());
        }
        if(isAuthenticated){
            navigate(`/account`);
        }
    },[dispatch,error,alert,isAuthenticated,navigate]);

    const switchTabs = (e, tab) => {
        if (tab === "login") {
          switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutral");
          switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToRight");
    
          registerTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutralForm");
          loginTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToLeft");
        }
        if (tab === "register") {
          switcherTab.current.classList.add("shiftToRight");
          switcherTab.current.classList.remove("shiftToNeutral");
    
          registerTab.current.classList.add("shiftToNeutralForm");
          loginTab.current.classList.add("shiftToLeft");
        }
      };

    return(
        <Fragment>
            {loading ? <Loader/> : (
                <Fragment>
                    <div className="LoginSignUpContainer">
                        <div className="LoginSignUpBox">
                            <div>
                                <div className="login_signUp_toggle">
                                    <p onClick={(e)=>switchTabs(e,"login")}>Login</p>
                                    <p onClick={(e)=>switchTabs(e,"register")}>Register</p>
                                </div>
                                <button ref={switcherTab}></button>
                            </div>
                            <form
                                className="signUpForm"
                                ref={registerTab}
                                encType="multipart/form-data"
                                onSubmit={registerSubmit}
                            >
                                <div className="signUpName">
                                <PersonIcon />
                                <input
                                    type="text"
                                    placeholder="Name"
                                    required
                                    name="name"
                                    value={name}
                                    onChange={registerDataChange}
                                />
                                </div>
                                <div className="signUpEmail">
                                <EmailIcon />
                                <input
                                    type="email"
                                    placeholder="Email"
                                    required
                                    name="email"
                                    value={email}
                                    onChange={registerDataChange}
                                />
                                </div>
                                <div className="signUpPassword">
                                <LockOpenIcon />
                                <input
                                    type="password"
                                    placeholder="Password"
                                    required
                                    name="password"
                                    value={password}
                                    onChange={registerDataChange}
                                />
                                </div>

                                <div id="registerImage">
                                <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                                <input
                                    type="file"
                                    name="avatar"
                                    accept="image/*"
                                    onChange={registerDataChange}
                                />
                                </div>
                                <input type="submit" value="Register" className="signUpBtn" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Fragment>
    );
}
```

userController.jsx

```
exports.RegisterUser = catchAsyncErrors( async (req,res,next)=>{

    // const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar,{
    //   folder: "avatars",
    //   width: 150,
    //   crop:"scale",
    // });

    const {name,email,password} = req.body;

    const user = await User.create({
        name,
        email,
        password,
        avatar: {
            public_id:"myCloud.public_id",
            url: "myCloud.secure_url",
        }
    });

    sendToken(user,201,res);
});
```

1. I have an id on Cloudinary and imported its Name, API_KEY, API_SECRET
2. Backend code works well on postman without Cloudinary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Postman** you are not adding image. But in client side login form, you are adding image alongside other data.

In backend you are getting email, name, password from **req.body**.But image data will be available in **req.file**.

As an example

```
    if (req.file) {
      const avatar= req.file.originalName;
      req.body = { ...req.body, avatar};
    }

await Model.create(req.body);
```

Comment: It worked I was actually following a old documentation, which led to this array. Thanks btw